# Do you need to reset asio::io_service after exception thrown by a handler?

Tags: c++, boost, exception, boost-asio

although boost docs say

> After the exception has been caught, the run(), run_one(), poll() or
>   poll_one() call may be restarted without the need for an intervening
>   call to reset()

I'm having a different experience.

In the exception handler I find io_service in the stopped state and infact any subsequent attempt to add async work fails, so that the following run() invocation exits immediately.

This is very similar to what I'm doing:

```
...
io_service ios;
do_receive(); // adds some async work to ios 
do try
{
    ios.run();
    break;
}
catch (std::exception const &)
{
    assert (ios.stopped()); //<----- ASSERTION DOESN'T TRIGGER. i.e ios is stopped
    ios.reset();            //<----- ...So I need to do this otherwise next call
                            //<----- to do_receive() fails to add more async work
                            //<----- causing next loop iteration's run() invocation
                            //<----- to exit immediately

    do_receive(); //same as above, adds async work to ios
}
while(1);
```

Adding a call to io_service's reset() before trying to add new async work seems to have solved the problem, but I can't see how this is going to scale in the case I have several threads calling run().

If any handler throws, the catch block would call a reset in that thread context and I guess that would perturbate quite badly all other in-flight operations.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something in boost docs?

Thanks,
Andrea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `io_service` will stop itself if there is no more work to do; that's probably what's happening here. If you want to prevent that, you can do so by creating an `io_service::work` object. The `io_service` will not stop itself as long as that object exists.

Comment: Gosh! You're right! I didn't notice the exception was thrown in the handler _before_ it could add additional work to io_service (by means of "chaining" the following handler), so unwinding back into the catch block it was leaving the io_service stopped because out of work. I could rearrange operations to have throwing code _after_ adding work to io_service, but that's brittle and hard to maintain, so I'll go for the io_service::work route.

Comment: "The `io_service` will not stop itself as long as that object exists." Not true at all. The io_service will also stop if you call `io_service->stop();`, regardless of whether a work object exists.